# QT programming, QtConcurrent run function

Tags: multithreading, qt, qtconcurrent, qfuture

I have a program which has class `MainWindow` that inherited from `QMainWindow`.
I want to run a specific function in a new thread.

Since I can't inherit from `QThread` so the best solution is to use `QtConcurrent`.
I stored `QtConcurrent` result in a `QFuture` but as mentioned in the QT documentation, the result of `QtConcurrent` can not be canceled by `QFuture::cancel`.

I see some questions like mine but the answers are to create a class which inherit from `QThread` that I can't.
So what is the solution?
Here is my codes:

mainwindow.h:

```
using namespace  std;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT


public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    ...


private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    ...
    QFuture<void> future;
    QFutureWatcher< void > futureWatcher;
    QPushButton *stop_pushButton_=new QPushButton;

private slots:
    ...
    void on_graph_pushButton_clicked();
    void generateGraph();
    void stopPushButtonClicked();
    };
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::stopPushButtonClicked()
{
    futureWatcher.setFuture(future);
    futureWatcher.cancel();
    futureWatcher.waitForFinished();
}

   ...
void MainWindow::on_graph_pushButton_clicked()
{
    loadingOn();
    future = QtConcurrent::run(this,&MainWindow::generateGraph);
}

void MainWindow::generateGraph()
{
    InsertLogs::getInstance()->printStatus(USER_GENERATE_GRAPH);
    GenGraph* gr=new GenGraph;
    connect(this,&MainWindow::loadingOffSignal,this,&MainWindow::loadingOff);
    graphType_=gr->generateGraph(persons_comboBox_->currentText(),
                      ui->graphResource1_comboBox->currentText(),
                      ui->graphResource2_comboBox->currentText(),
                      ui->graphType_comboBox->currentText());

    InsertLogs::getInstance()->printSuccess(SYSTEM_GENERATE_GRAPH);

    emit loadingOffSignal();
}
```

When I click on `graph_pushButton`, `generatedGraph` is called in a new thread, but when I click on `stop_pushButton` the `future` does not stop and the `generatedGraph` function executes completely.

Comment: I supose, your `generateGraph` function has some kind of loop, as long as it has long execution time and you want to call it in separate thread. So you can use `bool abortGraphGenerating` flag, and use `break` to exit the loop.

Comment: thanks, no it runs another function from an external library which has long execution time and i can't change the library function by adding a flag...

Comment: Why not create a wrapper class that inherits both your MainWindow  as well as QThread , to call that function.

Comment: Please read the doc about `QThread`, inheriting from the class is **not** the good practice to run something in another thread ! When it comes to thread you must first think about the data that will be read/written and split it accordingly into different classes.

Comment: MohammadKanan thanks, it may work, but is there not a simpler way?

Comment: @ymoreau thanks, is there another way to use QThread without inheriting?

Comment: @mortezaaliahmadi there is QtConcurrent where you just execute a function (but you must be cautious about the shared data), or to move a worker QObject to thread and then execute the slots in that thread, see the doc : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details

Comment: @morteza ali ahmadi, may be you can achieve your goal of `cancel` by implementing QFutureWatcher and event loop.

Comment: @ymoreau of cource, my function just creates a graph and saves it on disk, so I'm not worried about losing data.

Comment: @MohammadKanan can QFutureWatcher stop the thread of a Future? I think it can't

Comment: @morteza ali ahmadi, my understanding is yes it has `cancel` slot that can be connected to, `void QFutureWatcher::cancel()
Cancels the asynchronous computation represented by the future(). Note that the cancelation is asynchronous. Use waitForFinished() after calling cancel() when you need synchronous cancelation.`

Comment: @MohammadKanan thanks again, does it means i have to add these commands to my stop function?
`futureWatcher.setFuture(future);`
`futureWatcher.cancel();`
`futureWatcher.waitForFinished();`

Comment: @morteza ali ahmadi , depends upon your implementation but generally Yes.

Comment: @MohammadKanan i tested before, but it still does not work and the function executes completely...

Comment: @morteza ali ahmadi,  you need to update your question then , with the exact code and indicate your expectation from the code

Comment: @MohammadKanan thanks, ok

Comment: @MohammadKanan I add my codes yesterday. Can you help me?

Comment: @morteza ali ahmadi ,  the QFuture returned by `QtConcurrent::run()` cannot be canceled; but the QFuture returned by `QtConcurrent::mappedReduced()` can.

Comment: @MohammadKanan but does `QtConcurrent::mappedReduced()` execute a arbitrary function in a new thread?

Comment: @morteza ali ahmadi, Honestly this function is new to me, I dont know its limits .. you better check.

Comment: @MohammadKanan thanks you, but I think that just `run` function is done in a new thread...